Error converting the varchar to data type INT
I keep getting error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '789.08' to data type int.

The Sales column from Table3 is defined as varchar(20) null.
Please note Sales column includes varchar values such as 'Not Found' or empty space ' ', and decimal values such as '789.08'. I have never seen this before. I could definitely use anyone's support.
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AccountNumber, 
    a.LocationNum,
    b.DateSubmitted,
    CAST (replace(d.Sales, ',', '') AS int) AS 'Sales', 
    d.Description
FROM
    Table1 a 
INNER JOIN
    Table2 b ON a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
INNER JOIN
    Table3 d ON d.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber


tag with database platform

You're trying to convert 789.08 to an integer which obviously won’t be work, you’d need to convert it to a decimal

how can i remove the decimal and convert to whole number?

What database platform are you using? The error message sounds like SQL Server? Also what are your desired results for rows with values that aren't valid ints? such as "'Not Found' or empty space ' ', and decimal values such as '789.08'"

i am using SQL. the result from the likes such as "'Not Found' or empty space ' ', i want return value as zero (0) in numeric, and decimal value removed and return value as 789.

You probably need to use a CASE statement and then deal with each type of data in the column in its own statement

"I am using SQL" - however that comes in many flavors, each with different capabilities. So what dbms are you really using? SqlServer, Oracle, MySql, Sqlite,...? Please add the correct tag

Are you using Microsoft's "SQL Server"?

How do i use the decimal statement in case when statements?

yes i am using SSMS v20.

“How do i use the decimal statement in case when statements?” so, having researched CASE statements, what have you actually tried?

try cast/convert as money ... it is a little more forgiving.  For example try_convert(money,'1,708.52')   You then can convert to int if needed.

Integers are whole numbers like 1, -1, 42, and 789. These are stored in the various integer types.
789.08 is a decimal number. There's generally two ways to store them: floating point numbers or arbitrary precision numbers. These are stored as float and decimal or numeric. They both have caveats.
Floating point numbers can be imprecise. If it's important that 789.08 be exactly represented, for example if it's currency, use decimal(10,2).

Because the Sales column contains a lot of garbage, you'll have to do extra work to handle the non-numeric values. If you use try_cast instead of cast, unconvertable values will return as null.
TRY_CAST( 
  replace(d.Sales, ',', '') AS decimal(10,2)
) AS 'Sales'


For the life of me i do not get it why store anything in an integer column anything that is such as varchar, empty spaces, or decimals. do you have an example you can share how to use float, decimal, or numeric on this SQL i provided?

@Kkoruni I've added an example of use with try_cast. Garbage was stored in Sales because the data type of varchar(20) allowed it. To avoid this, use the most restrictive and appropriate data type and constraints so you know for sure what's stored in the column. This issue is known as "data integrity". Sloppy data makes everything harder.

thank you for the guidance on try_cast function. I did make a change to my query and created a temporary table to pull results in format as varchar, then used try_cast function. Now i have results in the format i need.

@Kkoruni Glad it helped. You shouldn't need a temporary table, you should be able to do this in a single query.

You should provide more information about sales column. If sales column is expecting a decimal value, you have to cast d.Sales from varchar to decimal, not to int. In addittion, if sales column is int, you can't convert 789.08 to int:
select Distinct
    a.AccountNumber, 
    a.LocationNum,
    b.DateSubmitted,
    TRY_CAST(replace(d.Sales, ',', '') AS decimal(10, 2)) as 'Sales', 
d.Description
from Table1 a 
inner join Table2 b on a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber
inner join Table3 d on d.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber

If TRY_CAST fails, it will return null, therefore, the query won't fail trying to cast a non-valid value.

An explanation would make this a better answer.

I tried the suggested decimal as shown but got this error:
(Error converting data type varchar to numeric.) Please note that the data does include values stored such as (Not Found).

@Kkoruni what you need is a try_cast, check the answer again

Hello Dale and Vicente,
Thank you for the guidance on try_cast function.
I did make a change to my query and created a temporary table to pull results in format as varchar, then used try_cast function.
Now i have results in the format i need.
Thank you to you and everyone on this post for helping me with this question.

@Kkoruni you can mark this (or the answer which helped you to solve the problem) as answer for the question

First of all can't convert decimal values to int directly,
and kindly provide more information of the Variables Declaration.
Hope the this link will be helpful
Geeks4geeks SQL convert Varchar to Int
